# For loop iterates thrice for the input when expected to iterate once

Tags: java

Using eclipse btw.

Why does this:

```
public class charCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws java.io.IOException {

        char entry;
        int count;

        for (count = 0;;){
            System.out.println("Press \" . \" to exit.");
            entry = (char) System.in.read();
            if (entry != '.')
                count++;
            else break;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of entries: " + count);

    }
}
```

result in 3x the amount of "count" as it should be? That is when I enter a, b, and c, for example, and then press '.', it says "Number of entries: 12"

I'm reading through `"Java, A Beginner's Guide"` and I don't understand what I did wrong? I'm new but not stupid so I don't see the logic behind this. Is it simply a bug or too fast of a mechanic behind the `for` loop to be used for such short code?

Comment: Print the integer values of the chars you read. I suspect some `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: Please mark your exact input.

Comment: exact input is as follows:
a
b
c
.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in your code. When you push `<enter>` you are actually inserting special (invisible) characters `\r\n` (also known as carriage return and newline). This is why every time you push enter you get extra characters.

You effectively have the input (spaces added for clarity only):

```
 a \r \n b \r \n c \r \n . \r \n
```

even though your console looks like:

```
 a
 b
 c
.
```

System.in.read reads one character at a time, so your loop will actually execute thrice for the sequence `a\r\n`, once for `a` and once for `\r` and once for `\n`.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. Now to figure out how to ignore the invisible keys... I guess I just have to include not \r or \n conditions from now on..

Comment: So long as you iterate through single characters like that, that is what you have to do.  That being said, you may wish to read into `Scanner` and `BufferedReader`, as you may be reinventing functionality they already do.